# Creating nested objects with es6

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, oop, ecmascript-6

I'm getting some data back from a local API, and unfortunately I don't have much control of the what's coming to me, what I am hoping is that I can transform the data after my API call using a function.

This is what I have currently

```
transformArray = () => {
    const { rawData } = this.state
    const obj = Object.fromEntries(
      rawData.map(category => [
        category,
        {
          aboveExpectation: rawData[0].value,
          atExpectation: rawData[1].value,
          belowExpectation: rawData[2].value,
        },
        console.log('category', category),
      ]),
    )
    console.log(obj)
  }

Output: [object Object]: {aboveExpectation: 6, atExpectation: 31, belowExpectation: 18}
```

The rawdata back from the API looks like this

```
    data [
  {
    "name": "Animal care",
    "Gap": "Above expectation",
    "value": 6
  },
  {
    "name": "Animal care",
    "Gap": "At expectation",
    "value": 31
  },
  {
    "name": "Animal care",
    "Gap": "Below expectation",
    "value": 18
  },
  {
    "name": "Calving and calf rearing",
    "Gap": "Above expectation",
    "value": 8
  },
  {
    "name": "Calving and calf rearing",
    "Gap": "At expectation",
    "value": 29
  },
  {
    "name": "Calving and calf rearing",
    "Gap": "Below expectation",
    "value": 18
  },
  {
    "name": "Reproduction",
    "Gap": "Above expectation",
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "name": "Reproduction",
    "Gap": "At expectation",
    "value": 25
  },
  {
    "name": "Reproduction",
    "Gap": "Below expectation",
    "value": 23
  }
]
```

So instead of having 9 separate objects, I would like something that's a bit more iterable, something like this

```
"Animals": {
    "animalCare": {
      "atExpectation": 1,
      "aboveExpectation": 13,
      "belowExpectation": 15
    },
    "calvingAndCalfRearing": {
      "atExpectation": 1,
      "aboveExpectation": 13,
      "belowExpectation": 15
    },
    "Reproduction": {
      "atExpectation": 1,
      "aboveExpectation": 13,
      "belowExpectation": 15
    }
  },
```

Now I have made some progress with my transformArray function but it's not quite what I want. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction please

Comment: Is the raw data you recieve an `Array`?

Comment: Yup, it's an array of objects

Comment: Please use `console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))` to show data. Copying and pasting from the console does not provide a good view into the objects.

Comment: `copy(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))` in Chrome's console will copy it directly to the clipboard.

Comment: Post is updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce the array of objects to an object, and create a property for each `name`, and init/update the value for each `Gap`:

```js
const data = [{"name":"Animal care","Gap":"Above expectation","value":6},{"name":"Animal care","Gap":"At expectation","value":31},{"name":"Animal care","Gap":"Below expectation","value":18},{"name":"Calving and calf rearing","Gap":"Above expectation","value":8},{"name":"Calving and calf rearing","Gap":"At expectation","value":29},{"name":"Calving and calf rearing","Gap":"Below expectation","value":18},{"name":"Reproduction","Gap":"Above expectation","value":7},{"name":"Reproduction","Gap":"At expectation","value":25},{"name":"Reproduction","Gap":"Below expectation","value":23}]

const result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
  const name = r[o.name] || (r[o.name] = {}) // create an object for the name, or use the existing one
  name[o.Gap] = (name[o.Gap] || 0) + o.value; // add/update the Gap value

  return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```